# Highlight element using angular drag drop 'onOver'

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, droppable

I am currently using [codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop](http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/) plugin for angular js and it has an 'onOver' event handler like in jQuery UI

currently i have a droppable element

```
<div jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onOver:'highlightRow'}">
```

and when I drag a draggable element it calls the function 'highlightRow' without problems, here is that function

```
$scope.highlightRow = function(){
console.log('in highlight row!');               
        };
```

However the issue I am facing is that I would like to add a class to this div via the onOver event handler but I cannot see an angularjs way of simply passing the element to the function 'highlightRow' so that i can do something like this:

```
element.addClass('highlight');
```

Is there a way that i can highlight this row using the 'onOver' event handler, I really do not want to write my own directive and bind the functionality i need to it, i would have thought the 'onOver' could do this otherwise what is its use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just store the over state in the scope and then use `ng-class`:

```
$scope.dropOver = false;

$scope.highlightRow = function(){
  $scope.dropOver = true;             
};
```

Assign the desired class based on the scope value:

```
<div ng-class="{highlight: dropOver}" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onOver:'highlightRow'}">
```

Comment: Thanks Retro, this solution works and gives me the functionality I require.

Comment: i must note however that this works only for highlighting the row however there are also cases where i need to edit the style attributes of an element (width, left position) and i cannot do this by simply adding a class as the values bust be calculated on the fly so i still need access to the actual element, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Try if the `highlightRow` callback receives an event containing the element (`.target`) as an argument. You could set the necessary calculated style attributes to your scope and the apply them with `ng-style`. But maybe it would be better to write your own directive if you have to do a lot of DOM manipulation ;-)

Comment: Thanks again Reto, what I have decided to do is use the onDrop method to call my own function **$scope.dropCall= function(e,ui)** and from this i can access the droppable element attributes using **var droppedOn = angular.element(e.target).attr('id');** or the dragged element using **var dragged = angular.element(ui.target).attr('id');** I know that it is not very "angular" to access DOM elements like this but in this case i think it will suffice

Comment: ** quick correction the variable dragged should actually look like this: **var dragged = ui.draggable;**